# Java Server Pages - collation when inserting into MySql?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, collation

I am using Java Server Pages and got problem with collation when inserting data from my application. My insert code looks like this:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <% Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp", "root", ""); 
       Statement st=con.createStatement(); 
       ResultSet rs; 
       st.executeUpdate("insert into table values (default,1,2,šđžćč)"); %>
```

In my database result looks like this š?ž?? (so he can see understand 2 letters but not all). How to fix it so all letters will be in my database?

EDIT : 
I can insert data with those characters via phpmyadmin, but i can't from .jsp file to database. It's like charset = utf-8 on my jsp file is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with adding to my connection from old path

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp", "root", "");
```

to

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8", "root", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Question marks come from this:

- The client has a valid character (good), and
- The `SET NAMES` agrees with the encoding that the client has (good), but
- The target column's `CHARACTER SET` does not include the intended character (bad).

Examples:

- `latin1` handles only Western European characters; trying
  to put an Eastern European character or any Asian character in
  it won't fit.
- `latin2` and `cp1250` can handle Czech, so conversions between them are mostly OK,
  but not between either of them and `latin1`
- `utf8mb4` is a superset of `utf8`.
  Putting a utf8 character into utf8mb4 is ok, but the reverse
  will result in a '?' in some cases.

The characters that were converted to '?' can not be recovered from the table.

How to fix future `INSERTs`?

- Using `utf8mb4` on the table column(s) probably works in all cases.
- Otherwise, pick some `CHARACTER SET` for the table column(s) that reasonably matches the client data.

The reason for only some of the characters being `?` (in `š?ž??`) is because `šž` exist in latin1 but the others do not.

Bottom line:  Change the `CHARACTER SET` in the table definition.

Comment: It's not problem with table definition. In phpmyadmin i can insert those kind of characters into table and they can be read from table into page with sql query. Inserting into database just ignores those characters and insert "?" instead of them. So i think the problem is in jsp page and don't know hot to fix it. I changed my collation in table definiton and for those columns in that table to "utf8mb4" and still "??" show up.

Comment: `š` and `ž` are available in `latin1`, but the other three characters are not, hence the `?`.  I believe the only way to get `š?ž??` is to have (1) utf8 bytes (good), (2) connection to mysql specifying utf8(good), but (3) `CHARACTER SET latin1` on the column/table (bad).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Problem with collation on database wasn't the problem because i could enter those values in phpmyAdmin, can fetch that kind of data from tables and with using useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 can enter that kind of characters into database. I tried to use "super utfmb4" but still the result was the same... after adding those params into connection link problem was solved.