# JDBC and MySQL partially work with UTF8

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, utf-8

I am using MySQL 5.6.27, Java Connector 5.1.36 on Linux, and I have problem with some of the Serbian/Croatian/Slovenian characters.

Database is started with

```
./bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --bind_address=localhost --character-set-server=utf8 &
```

Database is created with

```
-- CREATE USER 'my_test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_test';
-- CREATE DATABASE my_test DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
-- GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_test.* TO 'my_test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_test';
USE my_test;

CREATE TABLE proba
(
    content TEXT NOT NULL
) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';

INSERT INTO proba(content)
VALUES ('markovič marko SURČIN');

INSERT INTO proba(content)
VALUES ('Nikolić Nikola Ćićevac');   

INSERT INTO proba(content)
VALUES ('petroviš đura Đeram');

INSERT INTO proba(content)
VALUES ('Milošević Miloš Šabac');

INSERT INTO proba(content)
VALUES ('jovanović žarko Žarkovo');
```

This dump is imported into MySQL with

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.6.27/bin/mysql --user=my_test --password < schema.sql
```

Java client fetches data with

```
public class Serbian
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_test?user=my_test&password=my_test&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&collation=utf8_unicode_ci");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT content FROM proba");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String s = rs.getString("content");
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            rs.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is

```
markovič marko SUR??IN
Nikoli?? Nikola ??i??evac
petroviš ??ura Đeram
Miloševi?? Miloš Šabac
jovanovi?? žarko Žarkovo
```

(question marks are actually invalid characters reported by editor). In other words, letters Č, Ć, ć, đ are invalid while Ž, ž, č, Š, š, Đ are valid. It's weird that UTF8 partially works. Is there something that I should give a try or this seems to be a MySQL/Java Connector problem?

Comment: This is the console output, but could you try writing this in a file instead ?

Comment: Actually, it's written into a file, not the console.

Comment: Hmmm - you have **two** questionmarks where **one** character should be - this feels like edtitor tries to display ISO-* code. Can you give hex decode of that file or use different editor maybe (whare do you use now?)

Comment: Make sure that the encoding is being done properly by the database, the file, and the console.  Right now I don't believe you know where it's being lost.

Comment: @Jan:
Here is the hex dump:

`6d 61 72 6b 6f 76 69 c4 8d 20 6d 61 72 6b 6f 20  
53 55 52 c4 3f 49 4e 0a 4e 69 6b 6f 6c 69 c4 3f  
20 4e 69 6b 6f 6c 61 20 c4 3f 69 c4 3f 65 76 61  
63 0a 70 65 74 72 6f 76 69 c5 a1 20 c4 3f 75 72  
61 20 c4 90 65 72 61 6d 0a 4d 69 6c 6f c5 a1 65  
76 69 c4 3f 20 4d 69 6c 6f c5 a1 20 c5 a0 61 62  
61 63 0a 6a 6f 76 61 6e 6f 76 69 c4 3f 20 c5 be  
61 72 6b 6f 20 c5 bd 61 72 6b 6f 76 6f 0a`

@duffymo: I believe that I've set everything (see the post), the weird part is that it works partially. If it wasn't set, I guess none of the non-latin characters would work.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from the similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13234433/2144390)?

Comment: @GordThompson  Yes, then I get no Slavic characters at all, just plain question marks:

`markovi? marko SUR?IN
Nikoli? Nikola ?i?evac
petrovi? ?ura ?eram
Milo?evi? Milo? ?abac
jovanovi? ?arko ?arkovo`

Comment: Your letter Č shows up as c4 3f which is 쐿 in utf-8. There has to be something broken *before* you retrieve that string. How did you get the bytes?

Comment: I am executing the Java code given in the post with

`java -cp ".:./mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar" Serbian > java.log`

Comment: Which takes into account your local charset. I think it'd be best if you actually wrote the bytes you recieve from DB into file. By the way: rs.getString("content"); already does some conversion

Comment: What is the character encoding of your .java source file?

Comment: *"Actually, [the output is] written into a file, not the console."* - Is it stdout (System.out) output that is being *redirected* to a file? If so, then it may suffer the same limitations as console output that is not redirected.

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700235/java-server-pages-collation-when-inserting-into-mysql

Comment: Looking at the middle of that hex:  `53 55 52 c4 3f 49 4e` -- Assuming it is latin1, it says `SURÄ?IN`.  In utf8 the hex should be `53 55 52 C48C 49 4E`.  Because of the `?`, I suspect you have made attempts to fix it.  But in reality just made things worse.

Comment: The database creation script needed `SET NAMES utf8;`.

Comment: As described in the answer to myself below, `SET NAMES utf8` does not make any change. Importing schema to MySQL required the switch `--default-character-set=utf8`, otherwise some characters are corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Comment field too short. Not yet a "final" answer.

Where your letter Č should be hexdump shows up as c4 3f which is not valid utf-8.

Whereas

```
for(byte b : "Č".getBytes("UTF-8")) {
   System.out.println("-> " + Integer.toHexString(b));
}
```

Results in

```
-> ffffffc4
-> ffffff8c
```

And `\uc48c` is correctly printed as Č again.

You could check if moving from `getString()` to `getNString()` changes result.

**Wait a second**

There's 'c4 3f' everywhere some of your "missing" characters should be. The hex is already broken.

Comment: I tried also `getNString()` and works in same way. If hex is already broken, then it's a problem at Connector or MySQL side?

Comment: It might still be the output into file / system.out try writing bytes of string you read from db

Comment: In mysql you can see names as they're supposed to be?

Comment: In MySQL I don't see any of those characters, but that's okay because I did not set console charset. But I do have the same problem with the webpage. The given code is result of the investigation while working on Servlet/JSP/Tomcat application. I solved it by keeping Base64 encoded characters in MySQL. But I am curious about the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Well I suppose you'll have to do that onion-wise: layer by layer. Check bytes in mysql. See what bytes are received in getString () and so on. Have you tried inserting the strings from java?

Comment: I looks like you might be mixing up UTF-8 encodings and Unicode code points. `C4 3F` is actually not a valid UTF-8 encoding because the second byte starts with the bits `00`, not `10`. And `Č` is indeed UTF-8 encoded as `C4 8C` but that's not the same as the Unicode code point `\uC48C` which is `쒌` and UTF-8 encoded as `EC 92 8C`.

Comment: That totally possible @GordThompson. However it doesn't much affect the problem. The bytes received from the db are no longer what they were before and hace c4 3f instead.

Comment: Agreed. I just thought you might want to tweak your answer to try and avoid any (further) confusion for others who might be trying to make sense of all this. :)

Comment: @GordThompson which I did :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. The SQL file remains same, although adding

```
SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

doesn't hurt. Importing dump has to be changed by adding the switch `--default-character-set=utf8`:

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.6.27/bin/mysql --user=my_test --password --default-character-set=utf8 < schema.sql
```

Without this parameter, hex string in the query (`SELECT hex(content) FROM proba;`) shows corrupted hex string with the non-existing UTF8 characters. Finally, Java code has to deal with UTF8, so in the while loop the following line fetches the UTF8 string:

```
System.out.println(new String(rs.getString("content").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
```

Execution of the program and redirecting to file (`java -cp ".:./mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar" Serbian > java.log`) does not make trouble, so everything looks fine:

```
markovič marko SURČIN
Nikolić Nikola Ćićevac
petroviš đura Đeram
Milošević Miloš Šabac
jovanović žarko Žarkovo
```

@Jan, @GordThompson: thanks for help in better understanding the problem.